# Passing data from a foreach loop to a bootstrap modal in the same view

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

Inside a view blade.php, I have a problem passing data within a foreach loop to a outside loop bootstrap modal.

show.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH','action' => ['OrderController@update',$order_items->id], 'class'=>'table_form']) !!}

@foreach($order_items as $oi)
  <tr class="order-form-row">
   <td>
     {{ $oi->name }}
   </td>
   <td>
      <a class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteLineItemModal"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
   </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}


{{--bootstrap modal--}}
  <div class="modal fade" id="deleteLineItemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLineItemModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body edit-content">
                <h5 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete this line item? {{$oi->id}}</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="/orders/line-item-delete/{{$oi->id}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left">Yes, I am sure</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, not today</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When user click the delete icon for any record inside the table, it will pop up the modal to ask user if they want to delete selected row of record. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use javascript/jquery to pass values to modal.

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH','action' => ['OrderController@update',$order_items->id], 'class'=>'table_form']) !!}

@foreach($order_items as $oi)
  <tr class="order-form-row">
  <td>
   {{ $oi->name }}
 </td>
  <td>
  <a data-item="{{ $oi->id }}" class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteLineItemModal"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
  </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}


{{--bootstrap modal--}}
  <div class="modal fade" id="deleteLineItemModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLineItemModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body edit-content">
            <h5 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete this line item? {{$oi->id}}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="/orders/line-item-delete/{{$oi->id}}" id="lineitem"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left">Yes, I am sure</button></a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, not today</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
 $(document).on("click", ".btn-block", function () {
    var itemid= $(this).attr('data-item');
    $("#lineitem").attr("href","/orders/line-item-delete/"+itemid)
 });
 </script>
```